# Bootbox Dialog Modal Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

On my page, I have a table.  Inside one of the cells of that table is a link.  I am performing jQuery scripts if that link is clicked.  For instance if the link is clicked I want to show a Bootstrap Dialog.  This can be done easily with [Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/).  However, bootbox is not updated with support of Bootstrap 4.

Originally, the bootbox wouldn't even show because in Bootstrap 3, the class name to show something was `in`, but in Bootstrap 4 it is `show`.  I have fixed that, but here is how it looks currently.

[image]

The HTML that is generated by calling bootbox.js for this is:

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="bootbox modal fade show in" role="dialog" style="display: block;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="bootbox-close-button close" aria-hidden="true" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Test Title?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="bootbox-body">Test Message</div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-bb-handler="cancel"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancel</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bb-handler="confirm"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Confirm</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that in the `div` where the class is `modal-header`, the button comes before the `h4` element.  If those were switched, then this problem would be solved, but that is what I need help with.  How would I do that via the bootbox syntax?  I know I could just remove the title for now until bootbox becomes updated to support bootstrap 4, but I'm curious if this can be done.

Here is what I have so far:

```
                bootbox.confirm({
                    className: "show", // where I had to manually add the class name
                    title: "Test Title?",
                    message: "Test Message",
                    buttons: {
                        cancel: {
                            label: "<i class='fa fa-times'></i> Cancel"
                        },
                        confirm: {
                            label: "<i class='fa fa-check'></i> Confirm"
                        }
                    },
                    callback: function (result) {
                        // my callback function
                    }
                });
```

Comment: i think, this code may help you , 

   .bootbox-close-button {
       position: absolute;
       right: 1rem;
       top: 1rem;
   }

you can arrange that by adding this css in your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, you just reverse the positions (in the HTML) of the headline and the `x` like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div tabindex="-1" class="bootbox modal fade show in" role="dialog" style="display: block;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Test Title?</h4>
                <button class="bootbox-close-button close" aria-hidden="true" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="bootbox-body">Test Message</div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-bb-handler="cancel"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancel</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bb-handler="confirm"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Confirm</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When searching for `closeButton` here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/master/bootbox.js things do a little bit hard-coded to me.

However, if you change

`dialog.find(".modal-header").prepend(closeButton);`

to:

`dialog.find(".modal-header").append(closeButton);`

in that file, the problem should be fixed.

EDIT:

Actually, there's also `dialog.find(".modal-title").html(options.title);`

So, you need to **append the `closeButton` to the title**. Then it's gonna work as expected.

Comment: I can't do this in the HTML because the bootbox dialog is generated via jQuery.

Comment: Well, that means they have hardcoded the `x`. So, you'll have to dig into that Bootbox.js and fix it there.

Comment: Actually, there's also `dialog.find(".modal-title").html(options.title);` So, you need to **append the `closeButton` to the title**. Then it's gonna work as expected.

Comment: Okay, so where do I append the `closeButton`?  Or can I just add `.append(closeButton)` to `dialog.find(".modal-title").html(options.title);`?

Comment: Ahh your first solution, before the Edit worked.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Comment: Soo I'm backkkk.. when I publish to my server, I am experiencing the original problem that my question is about.. I've checked the `bootbox.js` file that's being published to the server and it's the exact same code that I fixed.. it shows `.append(closeButton)` and not `.prepend(closeButton)`.. so I don't know why it's not working when I publish..

Comment: I'd guess you need to clear browser cache in this case. After all, if all the files are identical locally with those on the server, it must work there just as well.

Comment: Just cleared cache, checked the published `bootbox.js` file and it exactly matches the local version and still same error..

Comment: Well, something must be different OR something isn't being loaded on the server the way it's supposed to. Create a brand new file with a different name, copy everything from the working local file to that and test. If the problem is still there, the server isn't loading something that you have local access to.

Comment: Okay, created a brand new file on the server.. then copied the entire project from the local version and pasted it into the new server folder and it works as expected.. so what do I need to do?  I just cannot find where the scripts differ..

Comment: *"it works as expected"* -- well, that tells you it must have been a caching issue. OR you had really really missed something there. Regardless, delete the old file, rename the working one to that old file's name. Done.

Comment: But when if I need to publish again?  I just forget publishing and just copy and paste the local version to the server version?

Comment: I have no idea what you do when "publishing" and what your publishing process is. But something within that publishing process may well be the cause of the problem.

Comment: It is the problem because whenever I publish, the error comes back.. I just do a normal publish through Visual Studio.. right-click on the project name.. publish to the server/folder I want to publish to.  Not deleting existing files on publish..

Comment: Well, as I said, it's either some sort of a bug there or some misconfiguration or one of the other possible million options. My guess is as good as yours. Try VS Code instead.

Comment: You might be used to Visual Studio, but I bet that for web development VS Code does everything just as well if not better. There is a remote possibility that Visual Studio is not quite as optimized for web development as VS Code. But again, that's just a wild guess, nothing more.

Comment: Just asked my coworker to try it and she got the same result unfortunately, but I looked [this](https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/issues/566) up and down the forum there is a CSS solution by firesharkstudios and so I put that in my CSS file and published and that worked.

Answer (score 22):

You can just resolve it by css:

```
.bootbox .modal-header{
display: block;
}
```

Comment: This is much better than modifying the bootbox.min.js

Answer (score 4):

it can be fixed with:

```
.bootbox .modal-header {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If people stumble upon this there is a now a version of bootbox 5 which supports bootstrap 4. You can find it here https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bootbox.JS/5.0.0-beta

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can re-order the dom in the bootbox callback function, like:

```
bootbox.confirm({
    ...
    callback: function () {
       $('.modal-header').prepend('.modal-title');                 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what i've done and it worked:
go to your js file (mine is bootbox.min.js), find this line :

```
var m=b(n.closeButton);a.title?d.find(".modal-header").prepend(m)
```

and change it for:

```
var m=b(n.closeButton);a.title?d.find(".modal-header").append(m)
```

So you just need to change it for "append" and the closebutton should normally be on the right side.